# returning a scraped variable from a function in python

Tags: python, function, variables

I want to create a function that returns a varibable I can write to a csv.

If I write:

```
from makesoup import make_soup

def get_links(soupbowl):

  linkname=""

  for boot in soupbowl.findAll('tbody'):
    for record in boot.findAll('tr', {"row0", "row1"}):
      for link in record.find_all('a'):
        if link.has_attr('href'):
          linkname = linkname+"\n" + (link.attrs['href'])[1:]
          print(linkname)

soup = make_soup("https://www.footballdb.com/teams/index.html")
pyt = get_links(soup)
print(pyt)
```

It prints what I want(all links on page) in the function and None with print(pyt)

Instead of print(linkname) in the function, i want to return(linkname).

But when I do I only print the first link on the page. Is there a way to pass all the links to variable pyt which is outside of the function?

Thank You in advance

Comment: In your function, add all the links to a list and return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, to get all the links in one go:

```
from makesoup import make_soup


def get_links(soupbowl):
    links_found = []

    linkname=""

    for boot in soupbowl.findAll('tbody'):
        for record in boot.findAll('tr', {"row0", "row1"}):
            for link in record.find_all('a'):
                if link.has_attr('href'):
                linkname = linkname+"\n" + (link.attrs['href'])[1:]
                links_found.append(linkname)

    return links_found


soup = make_soup("https://www.footballdb.com/teams/index.html")
pyt = get_links(soup)
print(pyt)
```

Or use yield, to return them one by one - while you process the output for something else:

```
from makesoup import make_soup


def get_links(soupbowl):
    linkname=""

    for boot in soupbowl.findAll('tbody'):
        for record in boot.findAll('tr', {"row0", "row1"}):
            for link in record.find_all('a'):
                if link.has_attr('href'):
                linkname = linkname+"\n" + (link.attrs['href'])[1:]
                yield linkname


soup = make_soup("https://www.footballdb.com/teams/index.html")
pyt = get_links(soup)

for link in pyt:
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from makesoup import make_soup

def get_links(soupbowl):

  links = []

  for boot in soupbowl.findAll('tbody'):
    for record in boot.findAll('tr', {"row0", "row1"}):
      for link in record.find_all('a'):
        if link.has_attr('href'):
          linkname = linkname+"\n" + (link.attrs['href'])[1:]
          links.append(linkname)

  return links

soup = make_soup("https://www.footballdb.com/teams/index.html")
pyt = get_links(soup)
print(pyt)
```